# what is the difference between the files with and without the dollar sign appended to the excel sheet in the source /target assistant in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

When I access an excel file at source /destination assistant in SSIS, sometimes in the dropdown I notice two excel sheets with same name one of them with $ sign appended. Would any help me understand what makes the difference?

Thank you for your assistance on my concern. You could find the screenshot attached my question.[image]

Answer (score 3):

A worksheet name has the $ appended to the name thus `Sheet1$` or `Male_Data$` The $ is not visible in Excel itself, the sheet name will only show Sheet1 or Male_Data. It is only in the internal addressable "stuff" that this comes into play

A [named range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-named-ranges-14513df5-0d79-4cd5-9a03-968905b244e6) is going to be what shows up without a dollar sign, thus `Male_Data`

Comment: Thank Billinkc for the response

Comment: No problem. If it solved the problem, click the check mark next to the answer